# Getting a list of nodes of a certain type sorted by number of votes

Tags: 7, rating, database

I would like to get a list of nodes of a certain sorted by votes (voting api) in one of my modules. Is there an entityFieldQuery that could do this? If not, is there a sql query I could use that might accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to list nodes sorted by votes..

You can see the query executed in views when you enable Show SQL Query in views settings (admin/structure/views/settings) in the view preview...